# Could not locate the launcher command

Tags: java, oracle, oracle-adf, jdeveloper

I'm trying to install jdeveloper 11g on win8  but i got this error

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Running the installer as administrator helped solve my problem.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Did you try ["Could not locate the launcher comand" running JDeveloper, Weblogic installers](http://salzotech.blogspot.fr/2011/07/could-not-locate-launcher-comand.html)

Comment: would be helpful if you post the solution here and then link to the article, rather than forcing the user to visit the page.

Comment: Nobody is forcing you to click the link

Comment: You shouldn't just give a link to another site as an answer, since the site may go out of date in the future. Instead, click the "edit" link on this answer, include the essential parts of the solution from that page here, and provide the link for reference. Read http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers/8259#8259.